# SOAP архитектура

Tags: rest, soap

Вопрос следующий:

Возможно ли используя SOAP архитектуру между клиентом и сервером, отправить запрос **get** или **post** типа, вместо xml, и получить ответ в виде xml?

Конечно стандартное использование SOAP "запрос"-"ответ" xml. Но интересует именно этот момент.

1. Как часто используется в SOAP запрос типа get, post?
2. Рационально ли использовать SOAP архитектуру при клиент-серверном взаимодествии в web приложении (если клиентом является браузер)?

Comment: В SOAP если функция зараннее извесна, то делают напрямую модифицированый POST вызов (т.е. ещё дополнительно присваевается Action в хедере, кодировка и т п). GET - в случае с браузерами - практически никогда (нет смысла), т.к. GET запрос нужен что бы, грубо говоря получить список SOAP ф-ций, а клиентское приложение затачивается под определённые функции, с определёнными параметрами. Что означает "вместо ХМL"  -  в пост-запросе всегда должна быть XML.

Comment: Если имеется ввиду, можно сервак настроить что б вместо xml он json хавал - можно "костылями". Прийдётся "отдельным" параметром имя ф-ции передавать, т.к. в JSON не заложено имя вызываемой функции, а в XML-SOAP заложено.